# Is there a way to use React Native to render a portal?

Tags: ios, responsive-design, react-native, portal

The intent of this question is to understand if there is a way to render a portal's content using React Native replacing the portal UI components with corresponding native views (any github projects to do this)? The intent is to avoid asking the portal (responsive portal) to be rewritten with say React (because lot of months has been invested in getting the portal to current stage and rewriting will be very expensive) but still be able to render the portal pages with a native look and feel instead of just wrapping the portal content in a WebView and showing it as native app?

Thanks,
Padmanabhan